# Controller Where clause - how to select where not like

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to return a sql query for the column status. I can have 3 unique status values: New, In Process and Complete.  I want to query for these 3 plus a Open which would include New and In Process but not Complete. How do I do that in my controller code? Can I somehow use a IN Clause?
Status would be the parameter that I want an Open.
Here is how I am doing it now (Just added the All Open, not sure how to tie that into the where clause:

My Viewbag:

```cs
List<SelectListItem> Stat = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "New", Value = "New" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "In Process", Value = "In Process" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Complete", Value = "Complete" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "All Open", Value = "Open" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = "" },
};
```

Controller Code:

```cs
public PartialViewResult ChangeDrop(string Status, string Tech)
{
    var helpdesk = from m in db.HelpDesks
           where (m.Status == Status || Status == null || Status == "") && (m.Technician == Tech || Tech == null || Tech == "")
           select m;
           return PartialView("DropdownTable", helpdesk);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query for the 'Open' `Status` you could use [Enumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-2.2). You could also use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netcore-2.2) to simplify checking whether the `Status` is unset.

Here is an example:

```
var openStatus = new[] { "New", "In Process" };
var helpdesk = from m in Context.Clients
    where (m.Status == Status || (Status == "Open" && openStatus.Contains(m.Status)) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Status))
    select m;
```